# Mysql select multiple id's

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to execute `queries` like this:

```
SELECT draw,SUM(uplata) as uplata, SUM(wonamount) as isplata,
 SUM(uplata)- SUM(wonamount) as stanje,
 COUNT(*) as ukupno_tiketa FROM macau.tickets
 WHERE  shop ='105' and status != 1 and draw = 1;
```

I need to execute that query 100 times changing only `draw = 1` to `draw = 2`, `draw = 3`, etc...

How can i do this to get a new row for each `select statement` in mysql `workbench` to be able to export everything to `csv file`.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to write a `store procedure` with a `while loop`:

```
drop procedure if exists load_test_data;
delimiter #
create procedure load_test_data()
begin
declare v_max int unsigned default 100;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;
  start transaction;
  truncate table new_table;
  while v_counter < v_max do
    insert into new_table SELECT draw,SUM(uplata) as uplata, SUM(wonamount) 
   as isplata, SUM(uplata)- SUM(wonamount) 
   as stanje, COUNT(*) as ukupno_tiketa 
   FROM macau.tickets WHERE
  shop ='105' and status != 1 and draw = v_counter;
   set v_counter=v_counter+1;
  end while;
  commit;
end #
delimiter ;
```

and later you can call this `procedure` to run it:

```
call load_test_data();
```

And you can dump your `new_table` to a `csv` file:

```
SELECT *
FROM new_table
INTO OUTFILE '[path]/File.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

**NOTE:** Replace [path] with the folder that you want the file to be in it. Keep in mind that the folder should be writable and all `full permissions` needs to be set. [Read this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)

Comment: @BlankName welcome :) but if this answered your question please marked it as answered so it gets closed. Thanks.